# how to extract querystring values from an URL string stored in MySql and save them in new fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, field, text-extraction

I have a field "url" in the table "test" of the MySql database, that contains a URL with querystring like

http://www.mydomain.com?q=xxxx&p=yyyy

I have created two fields "query_q" and "query_p" to store the query values in the table, however I can create a SQL to extract each querystring value from "url" field and save them in the new fields?

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to extract these pieces using `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: If it's possible, it would be more efficient to capture q and p and then insert them into your DB at the same time as URL.

Comment: I know, but I have to do it as post processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTR()` as Barmar said:

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77900/2/0).

```
update t1 set 
q=substr(url, locate('?q=',url)+3, locate('&p=',url)-locate('?q=',url)-3),
p=substr(url, locate('&p=',url)+3, length(url)-locate('&p=',url)-2);
```

Of course, for this to work, q has to be the first parameter, preceeded by '?' and 'p' the second. But if not, you can figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a quick & dirty solution, this might help:

```
UPDATE urls
SET
  query_q = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '?q=', -1), '&p=', 1),
  query_p = SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '&p=', -1)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2405f/1).